# Compiling/Binding AngularJS template and object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have an AngularJS template, which looks like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my_template">
    {{ name }}
    {{ age }}
</script>
```

and an object that looks like this:

```
{
    name: "Bob",
    age: 31
}
```

Is there a way I can make Angular return HTML after compiling the template and the data object? Please note that the data object in **not** inside my scope, it's generated randomly and doesn't exist (nor will exist) in the scope in any moment.

I just want to generate an HTML from the template and the data.

Also, note that I'm not willing to `$watch` the data object for any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's `$interpolate` was what I was looking for. 
The documentation is here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

Basically, what I did is:

```
var html = $interpolate("my raw template")({ data object});
```